# React setTimeout not being cleared or component updating after unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, runtime-error

I have a `React.Component` which can be in different internal `states` for animation purposes, state changes using a timeout, something like: `State A -> setTimeout(goToStateB, 2000) -> State B`.

You can think of the animation like in `State A` you see the message *Hello* and, after 2 seconds, in `State B` you see *Press X to start*.

The problem is that sometimes it crashes, with the error: `Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`. I use `React: 16.8.4`.

I am not able to reproduce the problem locally, but I do track errors live and this seems to happen pretty often. I know it's the issue with the `setTimeout`, because when I replaced (in a similar case, with the same error), the `setTimeout` with an `anime.js` animation that gets removed on `componentWillUnmount` the problem was gone.

The component looks something like this:

```
interface IState { finished: boolean; }

class TestComponent extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
    // constructor, other code, etc.

    private changeState(): void {
        this.setState({
            finished: true
        });

        // I also dispatch some other actions to the store, which might result in re-rendering of other components.
    }

    public componentDidMount(): void {
        this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this); // This is also something really strange, if I bind in the constructor instead of in componentDidMount, the `this` value is different/wrong. So `this` in constructor is referring to a different element than `this` in comonentDidMount ??
        this.timeout = window.setTimeout(this.changeState, 2000);
    }

    public componentWillUnmount(): void {
        window.clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <div>
            {!this.state.finished ? 'Welcome!' : 'Press X to start.'}
        </div>;
    }
}
```

It looks like somehow, even if the timeout should be cleared on `componentWillUnmount`, it's not always cleared, or it's cleared too late.

Any idea how to fix the issue, or how to further debug what's wrong and why that specific `removeChild` error happens?

Here is the (unfortunately minified) stack trace:
**NotFoundError**
Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

[image]

Some more details about the final calls that trigger the error. It looks like something in React internals does something with timeouts/expiration timers:
[image]

Comment: Shouldnt it be `this.state.timeout` instead of `this.timeout` when you clear the timer

Comment: In other words, add the timeout to your state

Comment: That is the reference to the `timeout`, why would I store that in the state instead of a `member variable` ?

Comment: Do you dispatch any async actions? Are there any actions which trigger some async code that expects `TestComponent` to be mounted?

Comment: The `TestComponent` does not listen/wait for any `async` requests/actions, so, in theory, it should be ok to be removed at any point in time (as it just renders the received props). Anyway, I do think `React` should not break like it does, it just looks like it tries to remove a `DOM element` twice or something like that.

Comment: Added an extra image, looks like `React` is actually using some timeouts internally, maybe sometimes the order is wrong, and component unmounts too late and doesn't clear my timeout and breaks?